# Understanding Google Geocoding API usage restrictions and other free API options?

Tags: python, geocoding, software-recommendations, api, google

I would like to use the google geocoding api to geocode a few thousand addresses.

I understand the daily limit for a free account is 2,500. I want to retrieve the coordinates and then map them in google earth, or maybe in another desktop GIS program.

The usage terms state the geocoding results can only be used in conjunction with a google map.

Does this mean I am out of luck?

I see there are several python geocoding libraries that use the google api, do the same restrictions apply if you are retrieving coordinates using these libraries?

I would like to find a geocoding api that I can use for free to geocode world addresses. From my research, it seems that google has most comprehensive and accurate information, but I want to be sure I can use it.

Comment: only on a google map you can use google geocoding results. you probably want http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/geocoding-service

Comment: thanks for the reply, it looks like right now they are temporarily not allowing the use of free and open app keys

Comment: Looks like a revamp coming soon http://devblog.mapquest.com/2015/05/01/looking-for-a-free-open-appkey-read-this/

Comment: yes i saw that which is good but i need a solution in the meantime

Comment: [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/demo) also provides a limited number of free lookups.